# Kubernetes kube-apiserver service not started after reboot system

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have setup cluster with kubeadm its working fine and 6443 port is up. but after reboot my system cluster is not getting up.

What should I do?

please find the logs

```
node@node1:~$ sudo kubeadm init
[init] using Kubernetes version: v1.11.1
......

node@node1:~$ 
node@node1:~$  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
node@node1:~$  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
node@node1:~$  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
node@node1:~$ 
node@node1:~$ 
node@node1:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
node1     NotReady   master    4m        v1.11.1
node@node1:~$ ps -ef | grep 6443
root      5542  5503  8 13:17 ?        00:00:17 kube-apiserver --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --advertise-address=172.16.2.171 --allow-privileged=true --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --disable-admission-plugins=PersistentVolumeLabel --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379 --insecure-port=0 --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --secure-port=6443 --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
node      6792  4426  0 13:20 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 6443
node@node1:~$ 
node@node1:~$ 
node@node1:~$ 
node@node1:~$ sudo reboot
Connection to node1 closed by remote host.
Connection to node1 closed.
abc@xyz:~$ ssh node@node1
node@node1's password: 
node@node1:~$ kubectl get nodes
No resources found.
The connection to the server 172.16.2.171:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`enter code here`
node@node1:~$ 
node@node1:~$ ps -ef | grep 6443
node      7083  1920  0 13:36 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 6443
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `kubelet` service is not running. Try to view its logs:

```
$ journalctl -u kubelet
```

To start the service:

```
$ sudo systemctl start kubelet
```

If you want to make `kubelet` running during the boot you'll need to enbale it. First of all check the `kubelet` service status:

```
$ systemctl status kubelet
```

There will be a line:

```
 ...
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; (enabled|disabled)
 ...
```

"disabled" entry means you should enable it:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable kubelet
```

But, highly likely it is already enabled, because this was done by "systemd vendor preset", so you will have to debug why `kubelet` falls. You can post logs output here and stackoverflow's community will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you did not install [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) from packages delivered to your
Linux distribution - as far as I know, installation on Ubuntu makes services
dependent on Kubernetes installed to avoid the situation you are describing.

The problem you are facing is the lack of support for starting kubelet by systemd or other runtime scripts.
[Systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd)  is a system and a service manager. On behalf of them, Kubernetes starts
on system boot.

You may try to repair your installation by copying/creating required systemd configuration
`kubernetes.service` to your installation `/etc/systemd` directory.

```
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes Kubelet
Documentation=https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /etc/kubernetes/manifests
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet \
  --api-servers=http://127.0.0.1:8080 \
  --allow-privileged=true \
  --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
  --v=2
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and enable service with systemctl:

```
sudo systemctl enable kubelet
```

The journalctl logs may provide information about problems with Kubernetes
Services if they still exist.

```
sudo journalctl -xeu kubelet
```

Answer (score 0):

check CPU and ram status. execute sudo
systemctl stop kubelet
sudo systemctl start kubelet
kubeadm reset --force and add calico once again and try.it shall work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).